# Blurry <canvas> Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, preloader

I'm re-asking this question...

I'm integrating this plugin into my site.

http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery-html5Loader/

It works great, however, the percentage counter is drawn on a  element, and the text comes out blurry (see screenshot.)

[image]

The text on the canvas is blurred, as seen here.

Essentially, the plugin itself simply preloads the files, and the author of the plugin has created several different forms of percentage animations and I'm including the code that creates the percentage. If you want to see the whole plugin, you can download it at the link included above. This code is included in `jquery.big-counter.js.`

```
/*global document window*/
;(function ($) {
'use strict';
$.fn.extend({
    LoaderAnimation: function (customOptions) {
    var defaults = {
            lineWidth:          20,                         /* set     preloader's line width */
            color:              "#ffffff",                  /* set preloader color */
            glowColor:          null,                       /* set shadow color */
            radius:             40,                         /* set the preloader radius (JUST FOR CIRCULAR PRELOADER) */
            font:               "normal 100px Lobster Two", /* set preloader font (you can embed a font by css and use it here) */
            onComplete:         null                        /* on Animation completed */
        },
        $container = $(this),
        // merging the custom options with the default ones
        options = $.extend(defaults, customOptions),
        self = this;

        /*
        *
        * PUBLIC VAR
        * Configuration
        *
        */
        var lineWidth               = options.lineWidth,
            color                   = options.color,
            glowColor               = options.glowColor,
            radius                  = options.radius,
            font                    = options.font;

        this.currentPercentage  = 0;

        /*
        *
        * PRIVATE VAR
        *
        */
        var $window         = $(window),
            supportsCanvas  = !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext,
            canvasWidth     = $(window).width(),
            canvasHeight    = $(window).height(),
            $canvas, $fallbackHtml,ctx;

        /*
        *
        * PRIVATE METHODS
        *
        */

        /*
        *
        * @description Used as fallback for the old browsers
        *
        *
        */

        var fallback = function () {
            $fallbackHtml.text((self.currentPercentage | 0)+ "%");
        };

        /*
        *
        * @description Clear the canvas during each frame of the animation
        *
        *
        */

        var clear = function () {
            if (supportsCanvas)
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            return true;
        };

        /*
        *
        * @description Draw on the canvas the animation
        *
        *
        */

        var draw = function () {
            var width = canvasWidth,
                height= canvasHeight,
                positionX = canvasWidth / 2,
                positionY = canvasHeight / 2,
                alphaPercentage = (width / 100) * self.currentPercentage;


            clear();
            //clearing canvas from everithing
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            //let's start drawning
            ctx.restore();
            ctx.beginPath();
            //draw percentage text
            ctx.font = font;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline="middle";
            ctx.fillText((self.currentPercentage| 0) + "%", positionX - 8, positionY - 15);
            //width of the preloader line
            ctx.lineWidth = height;
            //color of preloader line
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
            if(glowColor){
                ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
                ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
                ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
                ctx.shadowColor = glowColor;
            }
            ctx.moveTo(positionX - (width / 2), positionY);
            ctx.lineTo(alphaPercentage, positionY);
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        };

        /*
        *
        * @description Check if the precentage is equal to 100% to remove the preloader
        *
        *
        */

        var onAnimationEnd = function () {
            if(self.currentPercentage === 100) {
                $container.delay(1000).fadeOut(function(){
                    $container.remove();
                    if (typeof options.onComplete === "function")
                        options.onComplete();
                });
                $window.off("resize.preloader");
            }
        };

        /*
        *
        * @description Center the canvas on window resize
        *
        *
        */

        var centerLoader = function () {
            canvasWidth     = $(window).width();
            canvasHeight    = $(window).height();
            if(supportsCanvas) {
                $canvas[0].width = canvasWidth;
                $canvas[0].height = canvasHeight;
            }
            $container.width(canvasWidth);
            $container.height(canvasHeight);
        };


        /*
        *
        * PUBLIC METHODS
        *
        */

        self.init = function () {

            if(supportsCanvas) {
                $canvas = $("<canvas>");
                $container.append($canvas);
                ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
            } else {
                $fallbackHtml = $("<i class='fallback'></i>");
                $container.append($fallbackHtml);

            }
            centerLoader();
            $window.on("resize.preloader",centerLoader);
        };
        self.update = function ( prercentage ) {

            $.Animation(self, {
                currentPercentage: prercentage
            },{
                duration: 3000
            })
            .stop(true,false)
            .progress( function () {
                if (supportsCanvas)
                draw ();
                else
                fallback();
            })
            .done( onAnimationEnd );
        };

        this.init();

        return this;
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

So, does anyone know of a way that I can edit the source code to dynamically create the percentage text as actual text rather than drawing it in the canvas?

Comment: Where's the screen-shot and the code you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I included the screenshot. See the edit.

Do you want to see all of the code? There's several hundred lines.

Comment: @jwinton Just include the relevant part of the code in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace Blurry Canvas Text with jQuery Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561048/replace-blurry-canvas-text-with-jquery-text)

Comment: @CBroe it was, I said that at the beginning. No one had even seemed to see the first edition of the question. Is there a rule against re -asking a question that isn't answered elsewhere? If so, please inform, I had no idea.

Comment: @CBroe I did remove the other question.

Comment: I such cases, you should edit your original question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line:

```
ctx.fillText((self.currentPercentage| 0) + "%", positionX - 8, positionY - 15);
```

with:

```
ctx.fillText((self.currentPercentage| 0) + "%", ((positionX - 8)|0) + 0.5,
                                                ((positionY - 15)|0) + 0.5;
```

Canvas context default pixel drawing position is in the *center* of the pixel which means anti-aliasing will almost always kick in giving a bit blurry look.

Offsetting it by half pixel helps in many cases as the pixels are properly aligned with the actual pixel grid (some anti-aliasing will still occur with the text but it should give you a little better result).

Comment: no possibility of taking it completely out of the canvas?

Comment: @jwinton it's possible but that will require re-writting much of code replacing canvas with individual DOM elements instead. I just addressed the blurry text part (I dunno if you got to test it and see if it worked?).